# How can I pad an array in a specific dimension with a while loop?

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop, padding

I have an array, X4, of 4 dimensions:

```
X4.shape = (1, 4, 1, 3):
```

```
array([[[[1, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 1, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 1]]]])
```

I am trying to pad it with zeros on its first dimension until it reaches a length of 6:

```
array([[[[0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 1, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 1]]]])
```

I also need it to be in a while loop since other arrays will have varying starting dimensions.

This is the code I am using:

```py
while len(X4[0]) < 6:
    np.pad(X4, ((0, 0), (1,0), (0,0), (0,0)))
else:
    print(X4.shape)
```

But it just keeps running indefinitely until I have to stop the cell. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance as I am a beginner.

Comment: np.pad is not padding in place.  It is returning a new array with the padding, leaving X4 unchanged.  Run you np.pad command in its own and you will see it prints the array you are trying to create.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried that and I saw that is true. But I am not sure why, since I am passing the array name into it. How can I incorporate np.pad into a while loop? I need to pad variable length arrays to all have the same length.

Comment: It is just the way the method is implemented.  It creates a new array with the padding.  So you would need to use `X4 = np.pad(X4, ...)` to get `X4` to reference the updated array.  Of course, this means that every time you call `np.pad` you are making a copy of the entire array.  So, it would be more efficient to figure out the number of padding rows you need and add them all with a single `np.pad` call.